# Django ORM: How to filter in an annotation with Count() (subquery) without rawsql

Tags: mysql, django

For a list query I want to show how many prices there are for a specific product on a specific site.

I have found a way to do this with RawSQL, something I had never ever had to do before. Am I overlooking something?

```
    queryset = Price.objects.all()
    site_annotations = {}
    for site in Site.objects.all():
        site_annotations['num_prices_{}'.format(site.name)] = RawSQL(
            'SELECT COUNT(id) '
            'FROM `product_siteprice` '
            'WHERE `product_siteprice`.`price_id` = `product_price`.`id` '
            'AND site_id=%s', [site.pk]
        )

    queryset = queryset.annotate(**site_annotations)
```

**edit**

My models look simplified like this:

```
class Site(Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('display name'), max_length=50)


class Price(Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class SitePrice(Model):
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
```

Now the table I want is:

```
 Product | Nr of prices on Site A | Nr of prices on Site B |
 --------|------------------------|------------------------|
 Iphone  | 6                      | 3                      |
 Xperia  | 42                     | 66                     |
```

And I want to sort and filter on the number of prices, so thats why I need the annotation.

NB The name Price is a bit misleading if you don't know the rest of context, in this context it can be seen more like a Product

Comment: Could you please include the relevant parts of the models if my answer is incorrect?

Comment: I've added more context about what I want to do

Comment: Ive updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just need to filter the prices on the related site, then get the count of the number of objects.

```
Price.objects.filter(site_price__site_id=site.pk).count()
```

Although you may just want to remove the site price model and replace it with a many to many field

Answer (score 0):

I think the query that you want would look something like this:

```
qs = SitePrice.objects.values('price_id', 'site_id').annotate(d_count=Count('id'))
```

And to get the table that you want, you’d format it into a dict with something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
values = defaultdict(dict)
for x in qs:
    values[ x['price_id'] ][ x['site_id'] ] = x['d_count']
```

To print out this table, you would use:

```
price_ids = list(values.keys()) # you don’t need `list` for python 2
site_ids = set()
for x in values.values():
    site_ids |= set(x.keys())
site_ids = list(site_ids)
site_ids.sort()
prices = dict(Price.objects.filter(id__in=price_ids).values_list('id', 'name'))
sites = dict(Site.objects.filter(id__in=site_ids).values_list('id', 'name'))
print('         ', end='') # for python 3
# print '        ', # for python 2
for x in site_ids:
    print('%-8s ' % sites[x], end='')
print('')
for x, counts in values.items():
    print('%-8s ' % prices[x], end='')
    for site_id in site_ids:
        d_count = counts.get(site_id, 0)
        print('%-8s ' % d_count, end='')
    print('')
```